# Modification and expiration time of a file stored in data lake store

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using .NET API provided by Mircosoft to get the file info stored in data lake store in my code. These files are generated by usqljob job.
when i am using the following statement:

```
m_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(m_adlsAccountName,fileName).FileStatus.ModificationTime
```

then it gives me the number ticks since epoch which is a long type value.
Same thing happens when i try to get the expiration time of a file:

```
m_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(m_adlsAccountName,fileName).FileStatus.ExpirationTime.
```

How can i get the date time type value for both expiration time and modification? 
I know i can add those ticks to a datetime type value. But which datetime should i add it to?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Epoch is Jan 1 1970.

Comment: Are you sure? where did you find it? Can you please share the link?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: No, the datetime 1, January 1970 isn't working for me. It should be different for data lake store files. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Can you share what value is returned by data lake and what value should it correspond to in date/time. We could simply reverse engineer and figure out.

Comment: You were right. Epoch is Jan 1 1970. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and working fine for me:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
int ticks = m_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(m_adlsAccountName, file).FileStatus.ModificationTime;
```

The above line will return modification time in the form of ticks since the epoch.

```
modificationTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds(ticks );
int ticks = m_adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(m_adlsAccountName, file).FileStatus.ModificationTime;
expirationTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds( ticks);
```

It gave me the correct results.